# Minimum number of swaps for two 2D arrays to make the first one identical to other

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Bit Swapping**

You’re given two binary matrices, m rows and n columns. Both matrices have the same size i.e. same number of rows and same number of columns. Each cell is a bit either 0 or 1. You need to find the minimum number of swaps are required in the first matrix in order for it’s arrangement to match that of the second. If the matched arrangement can never be achieved output -1.

**Input Format**

The first line contains a single integer t, denoting the number of test cases.
The first line of each test case contains two space separated integers m and n denoting the number of rows and number of columns. Next m lines each contains n elements of the first matrix. Next m lines each contains n elements of the second matrix.

**Output Format**

For each test case print the minimum swaps.

**Constraints**

1 <= t <= 1000

1 <= m <= 100

1 <= n <= 100

**Sample Input**

```
6
2 2
00
11
01
10
2 2
00
11
00
11
2 2
00
11
01
00
1 7
0011011
0101101
1 1
0
1
1 1
0
0
```

**Output:**

```
1
0
-1
2
-1
0
```

**Code:**

```
for each in range(int(input())): #t test cases
    m = int(input().split(' ')[0]) # m and n dimensions out of which im using m only
    a1 = []
    a2 = []
    for i in range(m): # first matrix input
        a1 += [int(k) for j in input() for k in j]
    for i in range(m): # second matrix input
        a2 += [int(k) for j in input() for k in j]
    if a1.count(1) != a2.count(1): # counting if count of 1 and 0 are same in both matrix
        print(-1) # if not then print -1
    else:
        c = 0
        for j in range(len(a1)):
            if a1[j] != a2[j]: 
                c += 1
        print(c//2) # if yes then print minimum number of swaps
```

This is a Code Golf contest where shorter source awards higher score. Score is calculated by the following formula

```
(1 - s/10000)*100
```

where s is the number of characters in your source.

For example, if a correct source uses 1000 characters, a score of (1 - 1000/10000)*100 i.e. 90 will be awarded. The source limit is 10000 characters.

Comment: Is this code working as intended? Could you provide a unit test?

Comment: Yes, this code is working and have updated test case @dfhwze

Comment: What URL did you pull this problem from? In several regards the question as stated is unclear.

Comment: Is this a programing-challange?

Comment: yes, i have updated the question as well scoring method